# Is there a Javascript function to listen for new network events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to see if there is a 'DOMContentLoaded' equivalent of listening for other network events. For example, if the DOM is finished loading but the page loads dynamic content based on user interaction, can I track that new network event? Or at least know when one of those events occurs?

Edit: I am specifically looking for a document wide event listener rather than just an event listener for a single element.

Comment: Any DOM element that needs to load external resources has a `load` event for that element, so you can set up a `load` event handler on it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Is there a way to do this document wide? Rather than setting the on load event handler for just one element, can I attach it to the document to get all the new requests no mater which element is creating the new request?

Comment: The [`load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) doesn't bubble, so no.